# Netbeans made project disapear? How to recover?

Tags: java, netbeans, project, freeze, recover

I was working on a project, when netbeans freezed and closed abnormaly. When i reopend the project was missing, when i checked the netbeans workspace the folder was missing too.

Does netbeans keep a back-up for his projects? Is there any way to recover ?

Comment: I don't think it does. Did you save..?

Comment: yes i did, the project is older actually...

Comment: Are you sure the project folder was in the Netbeans workspace directory? Because there is no requirement that it has to be.

Comment: Yes, i'm absolutely sure, i remember adding some external jar there

Comment: I move accidentaly the netbeans system folder: "NetBeansProjects" or "Project Folder" to another location. I restore the folder to it's original place, the project reapeared in Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, hoping the freeze has not break the save system.

For file only it's easy :

> - Right-click on your project/package
> - Choose <kbd>Local History</kbd> -> <kbd>Revert Deleted</kbd>

Now if you have drop all the project you can do this (I've tried it has worked for me)

> - Create a new project with the same name.
> - Do the trick for files (2 first points)

If this trick doesn't work I fear you have no more Local History and will never get back your files...

Comment: Isn't local history only available if you have versioning enabled? I think if Rex had versioning there wouldn't be a problem in the first place...

Comment: Not at all, I've made my test on a project that is not linked to a versionning tool. It's the local versionnaling, Netbeans do it without asking us.